# Where is this log file?

Tags: apache-spark, logging, jvm, segmentation-fault, hadoop-yarn

Running a distributed application on Spark/YARN, I get the following error that kills an executor, and eventually kills the entire application:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4f85ab41b1, pid=3309, tid=0x00007f4f90a4e700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b15) (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libSalience6.so+0x7631b1]  lxaArrayTrie::Get(std::string const&) const+0x71
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/koverse/appcache/application_1537930191769_0049/container_e08_1537930191769_0049_01_000016/core or core.3309
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/koverse/appcache/application_1537930191769_0049/container_e08_1537930191769_0049_01_000016/hs_err_pid3309.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

There is a segmentation fault in libSalience6.so. So far so good!

But neither the core dump or logs files are where they say they are.

This error occurred on slv004 of a cluster, so the yarn application directory

```
/data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/koverse/appcache/application_1537930191769_0049
```

exists on that node. But a the container directory does not exist, and a `find` detects no log files.

Any ideas where this log file might be?

Comment: YARN containers are, by definition, _volatile_ -- the local files downloaded for a job, or created by a job, are nixed as soon as the execution terminates. Only YARN log files are retained for some time (or moved immediately to HDFS, if log aggregation is enabled).

Answer (score 1):

You probably have log aggregation enabled. If that's the case, log files are preserved in HDFS in TFile format.

You can check these logs using `Application history server`. This web app is accessible on port `8188` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`yarn logs -applicationId application_1537930191769_0049`